# Postgres 9.1 replication log streaming

Tags: streaming, replication, postgresql-9.1

I have set up streaming log replication and i am stuck on the last step. Master setup is done, backup and rsync has been successful. I can ssh from slave to master and from master to slave successfully. i followed the tutorial here http://blog.3dtin.com/2012/07/26/postgresql-replication-and-hot-standby-in-practic/

however, when i restart the db on the slave side after running rsync and creating the recovery.conf file as mentioned in the tutorial the slave is unable to connect with master and as you can see in the log below keeps on throwing could not connect to primary server error.

It's really strange for a noob like me that ssh is working and machines can talk to each other through ssh but TCP is erroring out ???? spent quite a lot of time on this, could not find the answer anywhere thats why posting here.

I am using noip2 as a work around for public IP and both master and slave are behind a router and ssh port has been forwarded. I also tried with firewall off on the master side but still didnt work. Please help resolve!

postgres@saro:~$ cat /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log 
2014-08-15 21:22:06 IST LOG:  database system was shut down at 2014-08-15 21:19:48 IST
2014-08-15 21:22:06 IST LOG:  entering standby mode
2014-08-15 21:22:06 IST LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2014-08-15 21:22:06 IST LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/35000020
2014-08-15 21:22:06 IST LOG:  record with zero length at 0/35000070
2014-08-15 21:22:06 IST LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2014-08-15 21:24:13 IST FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "mis-master" () and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

2014-08-15 21:26:23 IST FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "mis" () and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: So are you able to SSH from slave to master using both IP address and NoIP address?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean both IP address ?

NoIP gives you dns name which is mis-slave.ddns.net and mis-master.ddns.net in my case. also noip dynamic update client is installed on the master and slave which keeps updating the public IP to dns mapping after a configured interval.
to connect to master i use ssh mis-master.ddns.net and vice versa for master to slave.
if you mean ssh publicIPofMaster, then no didn't need to

Comment: BACKUP_LABEL="base-backup"

psql -p $PORT -c "select pg_start_backup('$BACKUP_LABEL');"
rsync -cva --inplace --exclude=*pg_xlog* $PGDATA/ <IP_OF_OTHER_HOST>:$PGDATA/
psql -p $PORT -c "select pg_stop_backup();"

these commands are run from master and base_backup is completed successfully on the slave. @Salem

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue recently. 
By default port 5432 is open only for locathost connection. You can confirm this with netstat:

```
abhishek@ubuntu:~$ netstat -ntl | grep 5432                                                                                                                                                                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

It was due to misconfigured listen_addresses in postgresql.conf

Update /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf to allow listen connection from all the addresses (default is localhost).

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Once you are done with this, check if pg_hba.conf is allowing connection from slave server's IP (10.10.10.101), using replication users(repluser).

```
host    replication     repluser      10.10.10.101/32        trust
```

Restart postgresql service to bring changes in effect.

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

To confirm if this port is now open, use netstat:

```
abhishek@ubuntu:~$ netstat -ntl | grep 5432                                                                                                                                                                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```